# Is it possible to apply h.264 compression to image?

Tags: image, image-processing, deep-learning, h.264, data-augmentation

Currently, I am applying h.264 compression to a single image.
As you can see in the picture below, I want to compress that image based on h.264 with 40 constant quantization.

[image]
However, there are no relevant functionality anywhere, such as Python-based libraries (opencv, ffmpeg).

Also, there is no github for applying to single image and well-structured h.264 algorithm.

So, is there any github implemetation or library to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why? h.264 "is a block-oriented motion-compensation-based video compression standard". Your image doesn't have motion (frames before/after) which is required for h.264 compression to function...

Comment: @sorifiend. I see. h.264 codec is for video compression not for single image.

Comment: For what it's worth the so-called [webp still image format](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp) is basically a single-frame VP8 video.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are cases (like academic purposes) that is does make sense to encode a single frame video.

There is an existing image format named [HEIF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Efficiency_Image_File_Format) that based on HEVC (H.265) codec, but for H.264, you must encode a video file.

You may use [FFmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) command line tool for creating a single frame video file:

```
ffmpeg -i input.png -vcodec libx264 -qp 40 -pix_fmt yuv420p single_frame.mp4
```

(Assuming your input image is `input.png`).

The `-qp 40` argument applies constant quantization 40.

> qp (qp)
> Set constant quantization rate control method parameter

See: [libx264 documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-codecs.html#toc-Options-31)

Note:
Since it's a single frame, the frame type is going to be an `I-Frame`.

---

In case you prefer elementary H.264 stream (without MP4 container), you may use:

```
ffmpeg -i input.png -vcodec libx264 -qp 40 -pix_fmt yuv420p single_frame.264
```

---

There are Python bindings for FFmpeg, like [ffmpeg-python](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python).
You may use it, for encoding a NumPy array that represents a raw video frame.
You may also use a pipe to FFmpeg sub-process as the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61260182/how-to-output-x265-compressed-video-with-cv2-videowriter) sample.

---

You can find source code for H.264 encoder in GitHub ([here](https://github.com/mirror/x264) for example).
As far a I know, the sources are implemented in C.

Without looking at the sources, I don't think you are going to consider them as "well-structured".

Comment: Thanks expert. I'm sorry if my words sound little harsh :))

Comment: FWIW: lower values of `qp` generate more encoded data (larger compressed files). Higher values generate pictures with more artifacts.