# Unknown input format: 'rawvideo' when trying to save animation

Tags: python, matplotlib, ffmpeg, pycharm

So, I get a strange error trying to save animations created with matplotlib.FuncAnimation using FFMpegWriter.

```
/home/j/PycharmProjects/venvtest/venv/bin/python /home/j/PycharmProjects/venvtest/main.py
MovieWriter stderr:
Unknown input format: 'rawvideo'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/j/PycharmProjects/venvtest/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 234, in saving
    yield self
  File "/home/j/PycharmProjects/venvtest/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 1093, in save
    writer.grab_frame(**savefig_kwargs)
  File "/home/j/PycharmProjects/venvtest/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 351, in grab_frame
    self.fig.savefig(self._proc.stdin, format=self.frame_format,
  File "/home/j/PycharmProjects/venvtest/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 3046, in savefig
    self.canvas.print_figure(fname, **kwargs)
  File "/home/j/PycharmProjects/venvtest/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 2319, in print_figure
    result = print_method(
  File "/home/j/PycharmProjects/venvtest/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 1648, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/j/PycharmProjects/venvtest/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/_api/deprecation.py", line 415, in wrapper
    return func(*inner_args, **inner_kwargs)
  File "/home/j/PycharmProjects/venvtest/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 486, in print_raw
    fh.write(renderer.buffer_rgba())
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/j/PycharmProjects/venvtest/main.py", line 24, in <module>
    anim.save('basic_animation.mp4', writer=FFwriter)
  File "/home/j/PycharmProjects/venvtest/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 1093, in save
    writer.grab_frame(**savefig_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/contextlib.py", line 137, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(typ, value, traceback)
  File "/home/j/PycharmProjects/venvtest/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 236, in saving
    self.finish()
  File "/home/j/PycharmProjects/venvtest/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 342, in finish
    self._cleanup()  # Inline _cleanup() once cleanup() is removed.
  File "/home/j/PycharmProjects/venvtest/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py", line 373, in _cleanup
    raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/bin/ffmpeg', '-f', 'rawvideo', '-vcodec', 'rawvideo', '-s', '640x480', '-pix_fmt', 'rgba', '-r', '5', '-loglevel', 'error', '-i', 'pipe:', '-vcodec', 'h264', '-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p', '-y', 'basic_animation.mp4']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I am confident it has nothing to do with the animation data, the error occurs even when I create a simple test animation:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
# plt.rcParams['animation.ffmpeg_path'] = '/usr/bin/ffmpeg'

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 2), ylim=(-2, 2))
line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)


def init():
    line.set_data([], [])
    return line,


def animate(i):
    x = np.linspace(0, 2, 1000)
    y = np.sin(2 * np.pi * (x - 0.01 * i))
    line.set_data(x, y)
    return line,


anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                           frames=200, interval=20, blit=True)

FFwriter = animation.FFMpegWriter()
anim.save('basic_animation.mp4', writer=FFwriter)
```

I am currently using PyCharm in LinuxMint and I have a fairly new version of FFMpeg (4.2.4) installed. Given that FFMpeg complains about 'rawvideo' which as far as I understand it is just a bunch of images in series, it seems unlikely this has anything to do with codecs. If I run ffmpeg -formats, sure enough rawvideo is in the list.

I have tried manually setting plt.rcParams, like in the commented line in the code above, with no success. I have also tried setting up both anaconda and venv environments, but I get the same error.
Annoyingly, I did not have this problem a few months ago when I was using Ubuntu. I have also verified that it works on my friends Ubuntu desktop, using the same simple venv as I set up for myself.

Any ideas?

EDIT: I use the fish shell, if that is relevant...

Well this is peculiar. If I start a terminal from within PyCharm and check supported formats, I get the following:

```
(venv) ffmpeg -formats
ffmpeg version 4.3.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 11.3.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --disable-debug --disable-doc --disable-static --enable-optimizations --enable-shared --disable-everything --enable-ffplay --enable-ffprobe --enable-gnutls --enable-libaom --enable-libdav1d --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-vulkan --enable-zlib --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libxcb --enable-vdpau --enable-vaapi --enable-encoder='ac3,alac,flac,libfdk_aac,g723_1,mp2,libmp3lame,libopus,libspeex,pcm_alaw,pcm_mulaw,pcm_f32le,pcm_s16be,pcm_s24be,pcm_s16le,pcm_s24le,pcm_s32le,pcm_u8,tta,libvorbis,wavpack,' --enable-encoder='ass,ffv1,libaom_av1,libvpx_vp8,libvpx_vp9,mjpeg_vaapi,rawvideo,theora,vp8_vaapi,libopenh264' --enable-decoder='adpcm_g722,alac,flac,g723_1,g729,libfdk_aac,libopus,libspeex,mp2,mp3,m4a,pcm_alaw,pcm_mulaw,pcm_f16le,pcm_f24le,pcm_f32be,pcm_f32le,pcm_f64be,pcm_f64le,pcm_s16be,pcm_s16be_planar,pcm_s24be,pcm_s16le,pcm_s16le_planar,pcm_s24le,pcm_s24le_planar,pcm_s32le,pcm_s32le_planar,pcm_s64be,pcm_s64le,pcm_s8,pcm_s8_planar,pcm_u8,pcm_u24be,pcm_u24le,pcm_u32be,pcm_u32le,tta,vorbis,wavpack,' --enable-decoder='ass,ffv1,mjpeg,mjpegb,libaom_av1,libdav1d,libvpx_vp8,libvpx_vp9,rawvideo,theora,vp8,vp9,libopenh264' --enable-encoder='bmp,gif,jpegls,png,tiff,webp,' --enable-decoder='bmp,gif,jpegls,png,tiff,webp,' --enable-hwaccel='vp8_vaapi,mjpeg_vaapi,' --enable-parser='aac,ac3,flac,mjpeg,mpegaudio,mpeg4video,opus,vp3,vp8,vp9,vorbis,' --enable-muxer='ac3,ass,flac,g722,gif,matroska,mp3,mpegvideo,rtp,ogg,opus,pcm_s16be,pcm_s16le,wav,webm,' --enable-demuxer='aac,ac3,ass,flac,g722,gif,image_jpeg_pipe,image_png_pipe,image_webp_pipe,matroska,mjpeg,mov,mp3,mpegvideo,ogg,pcm_mulaw,pcm_alaw,pcm_s16be,pcm_s16le,rtp,wav,' --enable-filter='crop,scale,overlay,amix,amerge,aresample,format,aformat,fps,transpose,pad,' --enable-protocol='crypto,file,pipe,rtp,srtp,rtsp,tcp,udp,unix,' --arch=x86_64 --enable-libopenh264
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
File formats:
 D. = Demuxing supported
 .E = Muxing supported
 --
 D  aac             raw ADTS AAC (Advanced Audio Coding)
 DE ac3             raw AC-3
 D  alaw            PCM A-law
 D  asf             ASF (Advanced / Active Streaming Format)
 DE ass             SSA (SubStation Alpha) subtitle
 DE flac            raw FLAC
 DE g722            raw G.722
 DE gif             CompuServe Graphics Interchange Format (GIF)
 D  jpeg_pipe       piped jpeg sequence
  E matroska        Matroska
 D  matroska,webm   Matroska / WebM
 D  mjpeg           raw MJPEG video
 D  mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 QuickTime / MOV
 DE mp3             MP3 (MPEG audio layer 3)
 D  mpegts          MPEG-TS (MPEG-2 Transport Stream)
 D  mpegvideo       raw MPEG video
 D  mulaw           PCM mu-law
 DE ogg             Ogg
  E opus            Ogg Opus
 D  png_pipe        piped png sequence
 D  rm              RealMedia
 DE rtp             RTP output
 DE s16be           PCM signed 16-bit big-endian
 DE s16le           PCM signed 16-bit little-endian
 D  sdp             SDP
 DE wav             WAV / WAVE (Waveform Audio)
  E webm            WebM
 D  webp_pipe       piped webp sequence
```

As is evident, there is no support for 'rawvideo' in the list above! Very strange indeed, I do not know which ffmpeg this list belongs to, perhaps it is a version integrated into matplotlib's animation class?

Anyway, if I uncomment the line setting the ffmpeg_path I am back at the old error. I did get it to work however, by changing the path from '/usr/bin/ffmpeg' to '/home/j/.conda/envs/venvtest/bin/ffmpeg'. Then I get the file to run, create the animation and save it. This works for my real files as well, which do not even run that particular conda-environment. They do not recognize or find the ffmpeg I have in /usr/bin though. I have no clue why but at least I have a workaround now.

Final edit:
It is solved. It was flatpak's fault. Lesson is, don't use flatpak (or snap for that matter) to install Pycharm.

Comment: It looks like FFmpeg version issue, try executing the code from [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61281547/4926757). Replace `-vcodec libx265` with `-vcodec h264`. Use full path: `/usr/bin/ffmpeg`. Let us know if you are getting an error.

Comment: It is not the encoding that is the problem, it is that ffmpeg cannot read the animation / data... For some reason it does not recognize the 'rawvideo'-format. Which is pretty darn strange

Comment: I meant that you replace the `-vcodec` in [my code sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61281547/4926757). Just for "diagnosing" the problem. Try to execute the code sample, and see if it's working or not. In case it's not working the issue if probably related to FFmpeg. If you don't want to try it... update your version of FFmpeg (the list of formats you have posted is much too small).

Comment: Ok. Problem is solved now. It was flatpak's fault. Apparently it's a known issue that pycharm and flatpak/snap/etc don't work well together. Apparently flatpak creates its own filesystem and that's why I couldn't link to /usr/bin/ffmpeg (in the flatpak filesystem ffmpeg did not exist there) Thanks for advice anyway!