# save video from rtsp link with less memory size- CV2 Python

Tags: python, opencv, video

for saving video from rtsp link, I used `cv2`,

```
out = cv2.VideoWriter('vid.mp4',
                              cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('m', 'p', '4', 'v'),
                              video.get(5), (int(video.get(3)), int(video.get(4))))
```

This code works, but saving 10 second video, it occupies about 3 MB of space which is very high.

the `.avi` format is also in same size, how to reduce the space of the video file without resizing the frame shape and how to achieve this while writing frames to the `cv2.VideoWriter`?

thanks

Comment: OpenCV is for computer vision, not for receiving and saving video. wrong library. use ffmpeg instead. -- do you understand that your current approach causes a complete **re-encode** of the video? that's because you use the wrong library.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz, is it possible to do in cv2?

Comment: OpenCV is **not a video compression/handling library**. it can't do **stream copy**, but you should want that. if you require to stick with OpenCV, you will get a re-encode. if you don't like the data rate, experiment with `VIDEOWRITER_PROP_QUALITY` but that may only have an effect for specific situations, not yours

Comment: @VishakRaj You may use FFmpeg (command line interface) instead of using `cv2.VideoWriter`. Take a look at my [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61281547/4926757). Use larger value of `-crf` argument for saving space. Try `libx264` codec in case `libx265` is too computational intensive.