# raw images to mp4 video with ffmpeg or cv2 fails with most codecs

Tags: python, ffmpeg, codec, scikits

I have a couple of numpy image frames (`np.uint8`, 4 in total) and want to create a mp4 file. So far so easy, it works **fine with the mpv4 codec**. But that codec compresses the files too much so that a lot of visual quality gets lost. So I tried a thousand of different codecs (h264, h265, av1, vp9 and others) and also other data formats (.mkv, .avi). I tried it with cv2.VideoWriter, skvideo.io.FFmpegWriter and ffmpeg-python. but no matter what I do, the video is either completely or only partially corrupted (approx the last quater of frames).
I use VLC media player to check the files. I don't understand what's going on here. I don't get any error messages. Strangely, sometimes, windows standard video player is able to read the video. So the frames are not always completely corrupted.

The skvideo code:

```
def to_lossless_mp4(img_list: np.array, target_path):
    height, width, _ = img_list[0].shape
    writer = skvideo.io.FFmpegWriter(target_path,
                                     inputdict={
                                         '-framerate': str(FPS),
                                         '-f': 'rawvideo',
                                         '-s': '{}x{}'.format(width, height)
                                     },
                                     outputdict={
                                         '-vcodec': 'libx265',  # h.264 codec
                                         '-crf': '0',  
                                         '-preset': 'veryslow',  # the slower the better compression
                                         '-framerate': str(FPS),
                                     })
    for i, image in enumerate(img_list):
        # some images are grayscale, since all frames need to be same size I do this:
        if len(image.shape) < 3:
            image = np.stack([image] * 3, axis=2)

        image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
        writer.writeFrame(image)
    writer.close()
```

the cv2 code:

```
def to_mp4(img_list: np.array, target_path):
    height, width, _ = img_list[0].shape
    if OVERRIDE or not os.path.exists(target_path):
        out = cv2.VideoWriter(target_path, cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'x265'), FPS, (width, height))

        for image in img_list:
            if len(image.shape) < 3:
                image = np.stack([image] * 3, axis=2)
            image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
            out.write(image)
        out.release()
```

the ffmpeg-python code:

```
def to_mp4(fn, images, framerate=1, vcodec='libx264'):
    if not isinstance(images, np.ndarray):
        images = np.asarray(images)
    n, height, width, channels = images.shape
    process = (
        ffmpeg
        .input('pipe:', format='rawvideo', pix_fmt='rgb24', s='{}x{}'.format(width, height))
        .output(fn, pix_fmt='yuv420p', vcodec=vcodec, r=framerate)
        .run_async(pipe_stdin=True)
        .overwrite_output()
        )
    for frame in images:
        if len(frame.shape) < 3:
            frame = np.stack([frame] * 3, axis=2)
        process.write(
            frame
            .astype(np.uint8)
            .tobytes()
        )
    process.stdin.close()
    process.wait()
```

edit: this is the output when I use the code proposed by Rotem:

```
[00:00<?, ?it/s]ffmpeg version 2.7 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.9.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      54. 27.100 / 54. 27.100
  libavcodec     56. 41.100 / 56. 41.100
  libavformat    56. 36.100 / 56. 36.100
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 16.101 /  5. 16.101
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.100 /  1.  2.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
[rawvideo @ 00000000051767c0] Stream #0: not enough frames to estimate rate; consider increasing probesize
Input #0, rawvideo, from 'pipe:':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 75497 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (BGR[24] / 0x18524742), bgr24, 2048x1536, 75497 kb/s, 1 tbr, 1 tbn, 1 tbc
x265 [info]: HEVC encoder version 1.7
x265 [info]: build info [Windows][GCC 4.9.2][64 bit] 8bpp
x265 [info]: using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA3 LZCNT BMI2
x265 [info]: Main profile, Level-5 (Main tier)
x265 [info]: Thread pool created using 16 threads
x265 [info]: frame threads / pool features       : 5 / wpp(24 rows)
x265 [info]: Coding QT: max CU size, min CU size : 64 / 8
x265 [info]: Residual QT: max TU size, max depth : 32 / 1 inter / 1 intra
x265 [info]: ME / range / subpel / merge         : hex / 57 / 2 / 2
x265 [info]: Keyframe min / max / scenecut       : 1 / 250 / 40
x265 [info]: Lookahead / bframes / badapt        : 20 / 4 / 2
x265 [info]: b-pyramid / weightp / weightb / refs: 1 / 1 / 0 / 3
x265 [info]: AQ: mode / str / qg-size / cu-tree  : 1 / 1.0 / 64 / 1
x265 [info]: Rate Control / qCompress            : CRF-24.0 / 0.60
x265 [info]: tools: rd=3 psy-rd=0.30 signhide tmvp strong-intra-smoothing
x265 [info]: tools: deblock sao
Output #0, mp4, to 'C:datamerged_datatestsubsubsub2022-10-12_11-03-44_3583968045500ns_io.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf56.36.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: hevc (libx265) ([35][0][0][0] / 0x0023), yuv420p, 2048x1536, q=2-31, 1 fps, 16384 tbn, 1 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.41.100 libx265
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> hevc (libx265))
frame=    4 fps=0.0 q=0.0 Lsize=     761kB time=00:00:02.00 bitrate=3117.4kbits/s    
video:759kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:1kB muxing overhead: 0.236524%
x265 [info]: frame I:      2, Avg QP:13.55  kb/s: 2078.50 
x265 [info]: frame P:      1, Avg QP:15.08  kb/s: 1560.14 
x265 [info]: frame B:      1, Avg QP:18.28  kb/s: 502.67  
x265 [info]: global :      4, Avg QP:15.11  kb/s: 1554.95 
x265 [info]: Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
x265 [info]: consecutive B-frames: 66.7% 33.3% 0.0% 0.0% 0.0%
```

Comment: I recommend you to try my [code sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61281547/4926757) "as is", and see if it's working.

Comment: interesting, thank you. Your exact example works. But not with my data.... I don't understand it.. If it was the data itself, why does it work with mpv4 but not with any other codec? why do some frames work and some don't?

Comment: I added the output to my question. I don't see any problems, do you?

Comment: Fist thing to notice is that your FFmpeg version is ancient. I recommend you to update to the latest stable release from [here](https://www.gyan.dev/ffmpeg/builds/#release-builds). The `r=framerate` argument should be an input argument (before the `-i`). In `skvideo.io.FFmpegWriter`, the input `pix_fmt` argument is missing from `inputdict`. There is still a chance that the issue is related to your input. What are the values of `n`, `height`, `width`, `channels`? Does `len(frame.shape) < 3` is `True` or `False`?

Comment: please present your data ([mre]). don't blame individual codecs for strongly compressed results. blame not having set a quality or bitrate.

Comment: @Rotem you were right, the ffmpeg version was causing most of the trouble. That was confusiong cause command 'ffmpeg' returned version 2023-02-13-git-.... 2000-2023. Anyways I updated ffmpeg. VLC Player still does not show the last frames which seems odd. But the online tool which I needed the mp4s for can read the files now. So my problem is solved!